# use method of module installed to parent class

Tags: python, inheritance, methods

I have a project with the class hierarchy: `Unit` <-- `SpellCaster` <-- `Necromancer`. In my `Unit` I try to `import` module `Observers.Observe`:

```
from Point import Point
from Observer.Observe import Observerable
from Observer.Observe import Observer
import Excep

import sys

class Unit(object):
    # __slots__ = ['_x', '_y']

    def __init__(self, name, hitpoints, damage, armor=0, location=Point(0, 0)):
        self._name = name
        self._hitpoints = hitpoints
        self._damage = damage
        self._hitpointslimit = hitpoints
        self._armor = armor
        self._location = location

    def ensureisalive(self):
        if self._hitpoints == 0:
            raise UnitIsDeadException()
    blablabla
```

My class `Necromancer` is inherited from `SpellCaster`, which is inherited from `Unit`:

```
from SpellCasters.SpellCaster import SpellCaster
from Units.Point import Point
from Spells.FireBall import FireBall

class Necromancer(SpellCaster):

    def __init__(self, name, hp, dmg, armor, location, mana):
        super(Necromancer, self).__init__(name, hp, dmg, armor, location, mana)
        self._spell = FireBall()

    def cast(self, target):
        Observer.addobservable(target) # problem is here
        super(Necromancer, self).manaspend(self._spell.cost)
        self._spell.action(target)


    def takedamage(self, dmg):
        super(SpellCaster, self).ensureisalive()
        if dmg > self._hitpoints:
            hitpoints = 0
            Observer.notify()
            return

        self._hitpoints -= dmg


    def __del__(self):
        pass
```

In `Necromancer` I try to use a method from module imported in `Unit` (test is commented). I got an error that python can't identify Observer. So my question is: how to use methods from module imported in parent class?

Comment: You need to `from Observer.Observe import Observer` *in the script where `Necromancer` is defined*, if you want to access it directly. Also, note that you can `from foo import bar, baz`.

Comment: You mean i nead to import module twice?

Comment: @ovod: yes. This is not as bad as it sounds, Python optimises for that.

Comment: Also, think about the alternative - every name imported into every namespace at every level you're importing from would be available in the current namespace. The potential for clashes and confusion would be enormous.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use names imported in different modules, even if that is the namespace for a parent module.

Just import the names you need directly; e.g. import `Observable` again for the module with the `Necromancer` class.

Importing does two things:

1. it loads the module if it wasn't loaded before.
2. it adds a reference in your namespace to the imported object.

Importing the same module in two different locations means it'll only be loaded once, but in your case you do want to create the extra reference to the `Observable` class in the module containing the `Necromancer` class.